# iOS : How to create view which is top of all screen

Tags: ios, twitter, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I would like to know, how to create a view or any control which is each time top of the view, here I am attached Music player screenshot where mini music player top of all screen (View Controller), I am also like to create that kinds of control when is mount on top of all View controller, in background if push and pop of VC will not affect of that mini control (view).

Please provide your feedback, if you know that kinds of any control the please pass the link.

[image]

Comment: could you be more specific please? what is the goal of this view ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:yourCustomview];
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your view-hierarchy, you might be able to bring views in the foreground or send them to the background.

```
[self.view sendSubviewToBack:playerView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:playerView];
```